# How to store a null value in mongodb via mongoengine?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

I'm using django with mongoengine and here is the point that confuses me:

How do I achieve {name: null} to be stored in mongoDB.
It's easily doable via **mongo shell**, however I can't find the way of doing this via mongoengine models.

Moreover,

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField(null=True)
```

seems like **null** argument doesn't do anything.

**1.** model:

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
```

usage:

```
person = Person()
person.save()
```

result in mongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("...") }
```

**2.** model:

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField(null=True)
```

usage:

```
person = Person(name=None)
person.save()
```

result in mongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("...") }
```

**3.** model:

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField(null=True, required=True)
```

usage:

```
person = Person(name=None)
person.save()
```

result in mongoDB:

```
ValidationError (Person:None) (Field is required: ['name'])
```

## Question:

What's the role of **null** parameter?

And how to achieve storing a **null** value in **mongoDB** via mongoengine?

Answer (score 1):

The `null` parameter actually seems to do the trick.

See below:

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField(null=True)

person = Person().save()

# check raw object that got stored
pymongo_coll = Person._get_collection()
assert pymongo_coll.find_one() == {'_id': person.id, 'name': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `default` argument is what you're looking for. From the docs:

> **class mongoengine.base.fields.BaseField**
>
> ...
>
> default – (optional) The default value for this field if no value has been set (or if the value has been unset). It can be a callable.

http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#fields